# <TD> background image should shrink based on text size

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm new to email design template.

I have a `<td>` with a background image. e.g.: `<td> Background image </td>`.

First, I want some text to be appear on the background image.
Secondly, this text is dynamic so I want the background image to shrink/resize based on the length of text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code please. You say its a TD background? Cross-mail-client background images is not trivial to achieve, you should start googling for that. See https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=14197

Comment: Thank you .. ll check it out.

Comment: you could add a span around the text and then put a background image on that - this way the span will only be as big as the text

Comment: You mean like this - 
<td><span style="background-image: url('bg.jpg');" />Test text size</span></td>

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get image backgrounds outside of the `<body>` tag in Outlook is to use VML.

Check out [emailbg.net](http://emailbg.net/)

I'm not confident that you can set the background image at a percentage, so even though you can adjust your span/div/table to wrap the text, I think the background image will just tile within that element.

Answer (score 0):

try adding span tags just after the td tag and style the span with background and if necessary with a block. As span tags are element specific they will give background only to the text which apperas dynamically. Hope this helps. It would be great if you create jiddle for that.